# How to display Taxonomy Imagefield on Menus via taxonomy menus

Tags: drupal, menu, taxonomy, imagefield

Im making a website that needs a kind of graphical menu on the main site of my page, where it must be all the categories of the site with an Imagen (just the image and the category name).

Obviously im using Taxonomy for do this.

I already added all the taxonomy terms and added the image field "Imagen" on the taxonomy terms.

But. I dont know how to display them like http://www.digital-2000.com/ Here (the categories on the center with their images).

Im trying to use views but i cant do a thing with taxonomy. I dont know what to do, im looking for a solution in google with no luck (cant find a definitive answer).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new View, from the "Show" dropdown you can select "Taxonomy terms". Then from the "of type" drop down you can select your vocabulary.

Uncheck "Create a page" and check "Create a block".

Now you should be able to access all of the fields for your taxonomy terms (including your 'imagen" field) and build a menu from them.

You can then use Context or block settings to place your taxonomy menu on your site.